# Can't retrieve output parameter with Go MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which inserts an entity and returns its new UUID, and while I can generate the code to create the right query, it errors out when using `go-sql-driver/mysql`. So the following code...

```
func test_insert() *sql.Rows {
    db := openDbConnection()

    defer db.Close()

    results, err := db.Query("call saveargument(null, 'Test Argument', 'Test Argument', '1', null, null, null, 1, 'test_user', @newargumentid);\nselect @newargumentid;")

    toolkit.HandleError(err)

    return results
}

func openDbConnection() *sql.DB {
    var db, err = sql.Open("mysql", getConnectionString(entities.GetConfig()))

    toolkit.HandleError(err)

    return db
}
```

... produces the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'select @newargumentid' at line 2

I'm not sure why such a basic piece of SQL could be so problematic. Any insights anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run more than one statement in a single `db.Query()` call. This is true of most query interfaces in all programming languages.

Call your stored procedure in one call to `db.Query()`, then query `select @newargumentid` in a second call to `db.Query()`.

Comment: Got it. I'm used to working with C# and ADO.NET where this sort of thing is a little more intuitive. I created a workaround for this stored procedure which works just fine, so I'll know that's a limitation for the future.

Comment: Note that this method of getting output from procedures does not work as of Go1.14 (not confident it ever worked, actually).

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Are subsequent calls to `db.Query()` not guaranteed to use the same MySQL session?

Comment: I believe so. Go sees all `@variables` in `db.Query()` calls as `NULL` and thus does not read in any information in `res.Scan()`.

Comment: @BillKarwin - I'm a bit late to this, but it's my understanding that you need to explicitly create a transaction in order to force the Go SQL driver to use the same session for subsequent Exec and Query calls.

Comment: @PhillipElm, You can't use the `sql.DB` object for multiple queries, because it might use different connections from the pool. But if you get a `sql.Conn` from the sql.DB, then you can use that connection for multiple queries (in separate transactions), and it'll be the same session.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, you can - see my added answer. Just call Begin() on it to get a transaction. The documentation (http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html) states that "In Go, a transaction is essentially an object that reserves a connection to the datastore. It lets you do all of the operations we’ve seen thus far, but guarantees that they’ll be executed on the same connection."

Comment: @PhillipElm, Thanks, I understand how that works when you use a transaction. What I mean is that if you don't want to group statements in a single transaction, you can still ensure the same connection, so you can make use of session state, like user-defined variables.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, right. Apologies, I misread your original reply. That is a good point. I've updated my answer below to reflect that. On an aside, I just re-read your answer and I noticed your use of Query over Exec. Do you see any benefit to using the former when invoking the stored procedure in this case? The former still requires a Close() call, and from this page (http://go-database-sql.org/surprises.html) it sounds like some drivers (MySQL namely) have issues with it. Genuinely curious about use cases here.

Comment: @PhillipElm If the stored procedure returns a result set, you must use Query().

Comment: @BillKarwin wow TIL that works. Until now I've been under the impression that didn't work with Go + MySQL due to a DB-specific driver level issue. Wrote a small test and voila, it worked ootb. Thanks for the info! +1

Answer (score 0):

I just tested @Bill's answer and I can confirm it does not work as at Go1.14. My workaround was to rewrite my stored procedure to "return" values by doing a select at the end:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
BEGIN
    # do stuff...

    SELECT 'bar';
END;
```

And then in Go just read it like any other query:

```
res, _ := db.Query("CALL foo()")
res.Next()
var bar string
res.Scan(&bar)
println(bar)
```

Note this method also works for multiple columns and multiple rows.